# WMI query of reporting service instances returns all instances regardless of parent sql server path

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, wmi

We have some code to identify the SQL Server instances and their associated Reporting Server instances which is returning unexpected results.

A machine has two instances of `SQL Express (2008) - (local)/SQLEXPRESS` and `(local)/EXPRESS_BOB` - each with their own Reporting Server.

Using WMI, we identifiy the SQL Server instances and this works as expected. For each instance we then query for RS instances as follows:

```
public void QueryServers(string wmiPath)
{
    using (
        var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
           wmiPath, 
           "Select * from MSReportServer_ConfigurationSetting"))
    {
        ManagementObjectCollection moc = searcher.Get();
        //
        // Process objects in moc
        //
    }
}
```

This is run for two values of wmiPath (note - requires Run as Admin):

> - wmiPath = "root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer\RS_SQLEXPRESS\v10\Admin"
> - wmiPath = "root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer\RS_EXPRESS_5fBOB\v10\Admin"

Regardless of the value of `wmiPath`, the `moc` collection always holds *two* values:

> - *moc[0]* ["InstanceName"] = "SQLEXPRESS"
> - *moc[1]* ["InstanceName"] = "EXPRESS_BOB"

How is it that a query under a specified SQL Server instances' WMI path returns Report Server instances that (I expect to) live under a different path?

Is this the correct path to be querying?

Comment: See these links...explains how the Reporting Services instance information is queried....check your registry...try the workaround.  http://nocentdocent.wordpress.com/2010/07/03/sccm-how-to-force-sql-reporting-services-point-to-select-a-specific-srs-instance-on-a-machine-with-multiple-instances-an-unsupported-workaround/    .... http://magalhaesv.wordpress.com/2012/05/24/system-center-configuration-manager-x-sql-server-reporting-services-x-wmi-english-version/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it appears to be by design (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152836.aspx )

adding `"Where InstanceName='<instance name>'"` to the query may help

Comment: Excellent - just the answer I needed. Thanks user1578107.